# Can an LLC make a DBA that ends in "LLC" or "Co" in California?

Tags: california, limited-liability-company

As the title states, I'm interested in making a DBA for an LLC that gives some indication that it's a company rather than an sole proprietorship DBA. Can the DBA terminate in "LLC" or "Co"? Most examples on the Internet show DBAs without such termination.

To clarify, the entity making the DBA would be an LLC in good standing.

Answer (score 0):

"You cannot add any misleading business titles such as “LLC,” “Inc.” or “Corp.” to the end of your name. These abbreviations give the impression that the business is structured in a specific manner, which has various legal and tax implications. There are strict requirements in becoming a corporation or LLC, as well as liability issues which could mislead the public if you use these monikers." (from [this website](https://www.upcounsel.com/dba-california), the first to come up in a Google search).

Comment: this doen't address the question which is about the case when the underlying entity is an LLC or a Corp. Can the entity XYZ LCC have a DBA of ABC LLC is the question.

Comment: You can only call yourself 'ABC LLC' if you have fulfilled the requirements, which XYZ has not. Whether "you" are a company or an individual is not mentioned, and does not seem relevant.

Comment: from the question "o clarify, the entity making the DBA would be an LLC in good standing." So in the example XYZ IS an LLC., The "you" is the partnership XYZ LLC.

Comment: @George; that's why I said it's not relevant.